# What does the symbol ::: mean in R

Tags: r, syntax

I came across this in the following context from B. Pfaff's "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series in R"

```
## Impulse response analysis of SVAR A−type model 1
args (vars ::: irf.svarest) 2
irf.svara <− irf (svar.A, impulse = ”y1 ” , 3
response = ”y2 ” , boot = FALSE) 4
args (vars ::: plot.varirf) 5
plot (irf.svara)
```

Comment: You could see help page `?":::"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the help file (you can see this with `help(":::")`):

```
The expression 'pkg::name' returns the value of the exported
     variable 'name' in package 'pkg' if the package has a name space.
     The expression 'pkg:::name' returns the value of the internal
     variable 'name' in package 'pkg' if the package has a name space.
```

In other words `:::` is used to directly access a member of a package that is internal (i.e. not exported from the NAMESPACE).

See this related question: [R: calling a function from a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165342/r-calling-a-function-from-a-namespace).

Comment: thanks, I really hate posting these sorts of questions but google is useless and the help file is very unkind to programming neophytes. May I ask under what help file this is documented?

Comment: Also do not search at google.org for R questions -- go to rseek.org.

Comment: #Shane, I've read the documentation, but as is often the case the documentation is so efficiently written that it becomes a bit obscure to neophytes (the very ones that need the documentation the most!).  This neophyte's question: what does "if the package has a name space" mean in your many-years-old-answer above?  Also, if the package doesn't "have a name space", then what does "::" or ":::" mean?

Comment: @WBarker when you create a package, some functions are marked with the export tag and are made available when you type library(mypackage)  or mypackage::myfunction() .   Some other functions are meant for internal use by the other functions of the package and are not made available when you type library(mypackage) or mypackage::myfunction().  

Using 3 ":" allows you to access these "internal" functions like so: mypackage::::myfunction()