# How to impute data with ml.lmer method in miceadds

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I am trying applying the `ml.lmer` to impute missing data to the following dataframe

```
num = structure(list(f = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 4), q = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0), w = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0), m = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), VAR1 = c(-4.95682177429289, -1.71885298325925, 
-1.87583453393747, -10.8948387329942, -8.08080625559951, -5.91060080742435, 
-0.441608813541267, -2.99216154761941, 2.84774625239502, NA, 
NA, NA, 9.99755147410283, 4.43052737120724, 14.5484885681107, 
2.76708477891915, -1.16534086049291, 9.89837800524645, -0.532905309286036
), VAR2 = c(1.97016982613686, 3.56723371979529, 3.51987609038002, 
-4.06622139517368, -2.12658955909922, -0.170511738732546, 7.61811332102057, 
3.13322534451211, 9.57371767396202, NA, NA, NA, 11.984901005381, 
5.72441513178024, 16.4228400177422, 6.70020469959361, 1.01261439823686, 
11.6615475503401, 3.77633131099577), VAR3 = c(10.1560372560437, 
10.1801786007975, 10.3578648604893, -0.140643528591531, 2.35612280120139, 
5.07415319782397, 16.1107541935183, 9.04452647025277, 16.0511108882419, 
NA, NA, NA, 12.8200201578453, 6.83486757060971, 15.3398531136545, 
8.2812335284254, 2.23463772852383, 13.3391933488311, 8.0877295387725
), VAR4 = c(0.498180346940768, 3.00685583337094, 2.35322477767466, 
0.282762095301972, 0.855921468843172, 2.66418197181061, 2.38290312756355, 
2.67461144477413, 2.62873089735811, NA, NA, NA, 7.40263746337343, 
5.65903049181366, 8.10425764744729, 3.64442942165172, 0.854005199532879, 
4.05097634729794, 3.18750289721644), VAR5 = c(5.07634106445921, 
5.4076172462957, 3.52593010658109, 3.29635357505705, 3.23171250638432, 
5.13231721794768, 5.82362215060103, 4.50936077199033, 3.73864718826752, 
NA, NA, NA, 6.79332702092993, 4.99273093417307, 8.33859938657718, 
5.99653923147157, 1.73552155550579, 4.99902596680605, 4.1363029065247
), VAR6 = c(7.77422356168883, 8.82730417906284, 6.36866211542873, 
4.85946360329115, 4.99276643284351, 7.11584125477072, 9.43260705283248, 
6.17689370466653, 5.8380426743645, NA, NA, NA, 6.36662668308545, 
4.75899543574918, 7.1874282896892, 6.15338369358482, 1.42804547517576, 
5.7142481318893, 3.55850893758603)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have used the following code to impute data

```
    library(mice)
    library(miceadds) 

   predMatrix1 <- make.predictorMatrix(data = num)
impMethod1 <- make.method(data = num)
names = names(num[,5:10])


    # method for lower-level variables (x, y, and z)
    impMethod1[names] <- "ml.lmer"

predMatrix[, c("f", "q", "w", "m")] <- 0

level <- character(ncol(num))
names(level) <- colnames(num)

#I did this because I would be interested in the interaction of the two columns (q*w). Don't know if there is need to enter ID here and set such interaction differently. 

vec = "w"
for (j in names) {
  level[j] <- vec}

level

cluster <- list()

for (i in names) {
  cluster[[i]] <- c("q")}

cluster

imputed = mice(num, method = impMethod1, predictorMatrix = predMatrix1, maxit = 1,
     m = 20, levels_id = cluster, variables_levels = level)
```

But when the imputation starts I got the following error

```
     iter imp variable
      1   1  VAR1Error in if (stats::sd(weight.obs) > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Cannot understand what the problem depends on. Could anyone help?

Specifically I would just to figure out whether the `variables_levels1` can account for the interaction between factors.

Comment: In the line call to `miceadds:::mice_imputation_create_type_vector`, you are using a function that the creator of the package `miceadds` did not export as shown by the `:::`. Are you sure that is your intention? There may be errors due to the fact that the author did not intend for you to use this helper function

Comment: Hello, what do you mean exactly that ..."the author did not expor"?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675502/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-r . `package:::function` is used to call internal, or helper, functions that the author did not export in the `NAMESPACE` of their package. Typically, if an author doesn't export a function, they don't want you to use it

Comment: Probably that might be the problem. But I found a different through that does not involve the usage of that function and the result is the same

Comment: Now I think it is re-edited finely. The error changed when replacing levels factor with numbers