# Possible cause of error in mice Error in if (stats::sd(weight.obs) > 0) { :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I am running the following NA imputation with mice, but I am getting some error

```
 mice(num, method = impMethod, predictorMatrix = predMatrix, maxit = 1,
    +      m = 20, levels_id = cluster, variables_levels = level)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  VAR1Error in if (stats::sd(weight.obs) > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Do you possible, what might it depend on?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Reproducible example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76194054/how-to-impute-data-with-ml-lmer-method-in-miceadds