# Access (exporting) function from namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

I know something similar has been asked before [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165342/r-calling-a-function-from-a-namespace), but the solution given there doesn't seem to apply in my case.
I'm trying to follow convention in creating a package by referring to functions exported from other namespaces and avoiding use of `require()` within a function.
I'm basically trying to prevent a function taking too long to run. For example,

```
fun <- function(i){
require(R.utils)
setTimeLimit(elapsed=10, transient=TRUE) # prevent taking more than 10secs
 return(i^i)
 }
>fun(10)
```

Works fine, but if I try:

```
require(R.utils)
fun <- function(i){
R.utils:::setTimeLimit(elapsed=10, transient=TRUE) # prevent taking more than 10secs
 return(i^i)
 }
>fun(10)
```

I get:

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
object 'setTimeLimit' not found
```

Changing `:::` to `::` doesn't change this behavior.
I'm open to any simpler methods to achieving the same objective. 
Also is it really so bad to have `require()` calls inside a function?
Many thanks!

EDIT:
If import works then great, thanks. Still in development so wanted to make sure it would be OK.

EDIT:
Apologies, it's there in base. Not sure how I missed this; I was originally using `R.utils::evalWithTimeout` and must have assumed both were in the same package. *looks sheepish*

Comment: Why not just add R.utils to your Imports?

Comment: Having `require` within the function call would be a way of allowing `R.utils` to be a `suggests` not `imports` dependency. Have a look at the way `ggplot2:::fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` implements the dependency on `maptools` and `gpclib` which are only required for this (and a few other) specific uses of ggplot.

Comment: Is `setTimeLimit` in the `R.utils` package? `"setTimeLimit"%in%ls(getNamespace("R.utils"),all.names=TRUE)` is `FALSE`. I see it in the `base` package. (That's R 2.15.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting this to prevent the question from showing up as unanswered, but will be glad to accept another...

```
isTRUE("setTimeLimit" %in% ls(getNamespace("base"), all.names=TRUE))
```