# S3 Methods not being explicitly exported

Tags: r, roxygen2

When I dispatch on the top level object, all the functions export to the namespace. Everything works as I would expect it to.

```
myfun <- function(obj) {
   UseMethod("myfun",obj) 
}

#' @export
myfun.this <- function()
```

**Namespace**:

```
S3Method(myfun,this)
export(myfun)
```

BUT, when I try to dispatch on an element within my object...

```
#' Subsets recoded data by a condition
#' 
#' This function filters a list, data.frame or vector by a condition
#' 
#' @param so A surv3 object
#' @param condition A positively stated condition or logical vector
#' @export 
subset.surv3 <- function(so, condition) { 
  UseMethod("subset.surv3",so$recoded) # THIS PART
}

#' @export
subset.surv3.categorical <- function(so, condition) {
  ....
  return(so)
}

#' @export
subset.surv3.continuous <- function(so, condition) {
  ...
  return(so)
}
```

**Namespace:**

```
S3method(subset,surv3.categorical)
S3method(subset,surv3.continuous)
```

However, the functions are not exported.

I would have expected:

```
export(subset.surv3.categorical)
export(subset.surv3.continuous)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I post something similar here:

- ["exporting S3 methods as functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091511/writing-as-data-frame-method-for-custom-s3-objects)

But, after all, S3 dispatching should pass thru generic function:

- the generic could "wrap" method call
- the S3 object could have classes in higher priority.

This should work without "explicit" method export.