# How to fix this error for raster package in R?

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I just started learning GIS via R, and I am using the raster package. It gives me the following error when I use the geodata package.

```
Error: 'geodata' is not an exported object from 'namespace:raster'
```

I used the following code:

```
States <- raster::geodata(name = "GADM",
                          country = "United States",
                          level = 1,
                          path = "path/to/save/file",
                          download = TRUE)
```

Found something similar on Stack Echange already answered here (['data' is not an exported object from 'namespace:my_package'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837428/data-is-not-an-exported-object-from-namespacemy-package)) but I believe it was a different context.

Comment: Which function from the `geodata` package are you trying to use? The syntax is `package::function()`. It wont work to run `raster::geodata` since both are packages. Try `geodata::some_function()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raster::geodata` simply does not exist (and that is what the message tells you).

You are probably looking for the outdated:

```
States <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "United States",
                      level = 1, path = ".")
```

And mixing that up with the replacement

```
s <- geodata::gadm("United States", level = 1, path = ".")
```

(but note that geodata returns "terra" objects. "terra" is the replacement of "raster")